# Looking for a "light" compositing manager for GNOME

Tags: linux, gnome, window-manager

I have an HP Pavilion DM3 (graphics is nVidia GeForce G105M), running Debian Squeeze with GNOME 2.30.

My preference for DE is Gnome + Metacity + Nautilus. I'd like to use [Docky](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/Docky), but it requires compositing. So I'm looking for a relatively "light" compositing manager. I realise that "light" is ambiguous, but I basically want something that won't chew through my notebook's batteries because of CPU or GPU usage.

I know that Metacity is [capable of compositing](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/03/31/enable-metacity-compositing-in-gnome-222/), but as far as I'm aware it's still testing. Some people report that it's smooth and lightweight, others claim that it eats up processor time. I've also seen references to a [problem with nVidia](http://live.gnome.org/Metacity/Compositing), but no actual details.

I'm not averse to Compiz, but I haven't used it before and I don't know what to expect in terms of "weight." And maybe there's something else I haven't heard of.

So can anyone recommend anything? Or dispel my idea that Metacity is not the right tool for the job?

(Originally posted on [GNOME forums](http://gnomesupport.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13957).)

Comment: I use compiz on my box that can handle it because it's pretty. I use metacity on a box that can't because it works. Why don't you try metacity for yourself and see? It's not that big of a commitment ;)
Oh and thanks for the docky link, installing now.

Comment: I use metacity, but I don't want to have any surprises while away from a power point, hence my reluctance to try out its compositing without more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than metacity, both KWin and Xfwm 4.2 support compositing and are ICCCM- and EMWH-compliant.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had a chance to try any of them out yet, but I'll accept it for the good leads. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I really like **xcompmgr**. It supports drop shadows, fading, transparency. It is in the package repositories of most distributions and it is lightweight.